# Wordpress blog to native iOS app

Tags: ios, wordpress

Looking to build a native iOS app based off an Wordpress blog. We implemented a JSON plugin to pull down the content but of course it comes in a desktop-ready HTML format and we need to manipulate the HTML on the app side.

Is there any way to build a mobile HTML 5 page that will give the native app the formatted HTML versus doing the manipulation with XCODE?

Comment: I would manipulate the HTML on the server side before sending down to the phone, that's not something that the app should really handle IMO. But essentially you just use a `UIWebView` if you're going to be using HTML. From what you're describing though you seem to be using 'native' as a buzzword. Your project sounds far better off as a mobile-friendly website instead of app.

Comment: I guess this exactly what I was trying to figure out, how to best manipulate the HTML on the server side. Should we create a mobile version of the code that will be displayed inside the WebView? The site already has a mobile version of it, but we need a native app also.

Comment: What do you want to do with the native app? Is there a point to? If it's based off a blog, you probably don't need a native app is my point. What features do you want specifically that are native that you can't achieve using a mobile-friendly site?

Comment: For some reason people still want the native app. And we can use that with push notifications and other features specific to native apps.